# How do I set an NSTableColumn headerCell stringValue in swift?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstablecolumn

The documentation makes it look as if it would be as easy as this:

```
var tc = NSTableColumn(identifier: "mycolumn")
tc.headerCell.stStringValue("foo")
```

The last line of code is a compile error, which I don't understand. On top of that I get a couple of different compile error message for this exact same line of code depending on what mood XCode seems to be in. I've seen the following compile errors:

1. AnyObject does not have a member named 'stStringValue'
2. Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSString' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'

I get this when try setting a variable and putting that in there:

3. Cannot convert the expression's type 'String' to type 'String?!'

I get this when I try the `"foo \(bar)"` variant:

4. Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'

Hilariously enough if I declare a variable with type `String?!` it says it `Cannot convert the expression's type 'String?!' to type 'String?!'`

I don't understand what is going on. Is this a bug?

If I try this in a playground, the playground actually wants to autocomplete with an extra argument, this format:

```
tc.headerCell.setStringValue("foo", resolvingEntities: false)
```

This has no compile time errors, but results in a seg fault at run time. This format is also not in the documentation.

I really have no idea what's going on and the error messages aren't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work, despite the terrible error messages. The problem is that `headerCell` is typed as `AnyObject`, I had to cast it. The second problem was that in swift land it's a property, not a method.

This finally worked:

```
var tc = NSTableColumn(identifier: "mycolumn") 
let hc = column1.headerCell as NSTableHeaderCell
hc.stringValue = "foo"
```